# My php email form is not returning the data entered by the user

Tags: php, forms, email

As stated in the title, my webform is not returning the user information in the email, although the field labels are being returned.

I think this is an issue where the HTML is not structured to relate back to the php field name, but I am not sure how to format that.

Can anyone set me on the path?

This is the HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span5">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address">
                </div>
                <div class="span7">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required class="input-block-level" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</button>

        </form>
```

And this is the php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'Example@email.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Comment: no `name attribute` in any of text field

Comment: As a side note, it might be worth removing the @ symbols and resolving the issues that are being suppressed. It generally makes it easier to debug stuff in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your inputs a `name` attribute, such as:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name" />
```

Then you will be able to access the `$_POST` data as you currently are. Check out the [name attribute docs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your inputs does not have `name` attributes:

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" name="first_name" placeholder="Your First Name">

<input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" name="last_name" placeholder="Your Last Name">

<input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
```

---

Secondly, you need to use `<input>` instead of `<button>`. Otherwise, your form will not be submitted.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right">Send Message</input>
```

---

Thirdly, you need to check if the form is submitted by using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

```
// will return true if the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    // other parts of your code
}
```

---

Lastly, you shouldn't suppress the error messages by removing the `@` as they are very useful in helping you to debug your errors, especially when you have a syntax error.

Comment: "Firstly, your inputs does not have name attributes:"
All you did is repeat my code back to me, and that isn't very helpful. Using the instructions posted by Stuart I have arrived here:

<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name" /> 

But I am still not receiving the data.


"Secondly, you need to use <input> instead of <button>. Otherwise, your form will not be submitted."

My form is being submitted and I am receiving email, the only issue is that the users data is not being retuned with said form.